# How to draw text and image as textures on IOS Swift OpenglES 1.0/1.1/2.0

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, swift2, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to render texture of png images and also draw strings as textures on Swift by using OpenglES 1.0 . But none of examples I have googled and found here aint working. I spent more than enough time for it and I need to figure this out.

On screen only the non-textured drawers are shown, I remove all the triangle based drawers and there is no issue about camera angle or views, issue is about texture rendering.

Thanks to anyone can help me, here are my simplified codes for drawing png to texture, but shows nothing, not even white boxes;

This is the renderer class;

```
import GLKit
import SWXMLHash
class MapViewController: GLKViewController {
    @IBOutlet var glView: GLKView!
    var rViewController : UIViewController? = nil
    var context : EAGLContext!
    var ratio : Float!
    var size : Float!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.context = EAGLContext.init(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES1)
        if self.context == nil {
            Util.log("failed to create context for self")
        }
        glView.context = self.context
        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(self.context)

        glClearColor(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.5)
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_CULL_FACE))
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_DEPTH_TEST))
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
        glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_SRC_ALPHA), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA))

    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if firstInit {
            let width = glView.frame.size.width
            let height = glView.frame.size.height
            glViewport(0, 0, Int32(width), Int32(height))
            let fieldOfView = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(60)
            glEnable(GLenum(GL_NORMALIZE))
            self.ratio = Float(width)/Float(height)
            glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_PROJECTION))
            glLoadIdentity()
            size = zNear * Float(tan(Double(fieldOfView/2.0)))
            glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (ratio), size / (ratio), zNear, zFar)
            glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_MODELVIEW))
            glLoadIdentity()
        }
    }

    override func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
        glPushMatrix()
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT))
        glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_MODELVIEW))
        glLoadIdentity()
        glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY))
        glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_COLOR_ARRAY))

            glEnable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))
            //     glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
            //     glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY))
            glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY))

            let fl = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            let drawer = IconDrawer(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, size:150, roomCoords: fl, exampleimage)
            drawer.draw()

            glDisable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))
            glDisableClientState(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY))    

        glDisableClientState(GLenum(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY));
        glDisableClientState(GLenum(GL_COLOR_ARRAY));
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

and this is the drawer class;

```
import Foundation
class IconDrawer : Mesh {
    let normals : [GLfloat] =  [
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
    let textureCoordinates : [Float] = [0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0]
    let indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]

    var coordinates : CGPoint? = nil
    var texture:GLuint=0
    static var currentScreenMid = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    init(x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, size : Int, roomCoords : CGPoint, imageName : String) {
        super.init()
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices

        self.coordinates = roomCoords

        let w = Float((size)/1000);
        let h = Float((size)/1000);
        let vertices : [Float] = [-w+x, -h+y, z+Zunit,
            w+x, -h+y, z+Zunit,
            w+x, h+y, z+Zunit,
            -w+x, h+y, z+Zunit]
        setIndices(indices);
        setVertices(vertices);
        setTextureCoordinates(textureCoordinates);

        //PART 1 LOAD PNG

    let image = UIImage(named : imageName)
    let iwidth = CGImageGetWidth(image?.CGImage)
    let iheight = CGImageGetHeight(image?.CGImage)

    let imageData  = malloc(iwidth * iheight * 4)

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let imageContext : CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, iwidth, iheight, 8, iwidth * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo.rawValue)!
    CGContextClearRect(imageContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(iwidth), CGFloat(iheight)))
    CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0, CGFloat((iheight - iheight)))
    CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGFloat(iwidth), CGFloat(iheight)), image?.CGImage)
    glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLint(0), GL_RGBA, Int32(iwidth), Int32(iheight), GLint(0), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), imageData)

    self.w = GLsizei(Int(image!.size.width))
    self.h = GLsizei(Int(image!.size.height))

    loadBitmap(imageData)
    fl.bitmaps.append(imageData)

    //PART 2 CREATE TEXTURE WITH THE IMAGE DATA
    glGenTextures(1, &texture)
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture)
    glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), Int32(0), GL_RGBA, GLsizei(Int(image!.size.width)), GLsizei(Int(image!.size.height)), Int32(0), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), imageData)

    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GLint(GL_LINEAR))

    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GLint(GL_LINEAR))

    if image != nil {
        let imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image!.size.width, image!.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        image?.drawInRect(imageRect)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }


}

override func draw() {

    //PART 3 RENDER
    glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY));
    glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY));
    glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY));
    glEnable(UInt32(GL_TEXTURE_2D));
    glEnable(UInt32(GL_BLEND));
    glBlendFunc(UInt32(GL_SRC_ALPHA), UInt32(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));

    Drawer.printGLErrors()
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture)
    Drawer.printGLErrors()
    glVertexPointer(Int32(2), GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLsizei(0), self.mVerticesBuffer!)
    Drawer.printGLErrors()
    glNormalPointer(GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLsizei(0), normals)
    Drawer.printGLErrors()
    glTexCoordPointer(Int32(2), GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLsizei(0), textureCoordinates)
    Drawer.printGLErrors()
    glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), 0, 4)
    Drawer.printGLErrors()

}
```

}

Comment: What is the imageName for if you don't use it? What do you actually see? Can you see the clear color? Can you see the primitives if you disable the textures?

Comment: Sorry about it while I was trying to remove irrelevant lines, by a mistake I removed that, edited now.
Yes, triangle based renderer works perfect, I even use scale, drag, rotate and many more. Except the textures everything works.

Comment: Ok but when you draw the textures you see nothing at al, not even some black area? If so try disabling the blend. If this will produce black shapes you texture data are for some reason empty (0,0,0,0) will produce transparent pixels ergo nothing is visible with current blend mode setting. So if this is the case first check if the image is present, if it is correct and if raw image data make sense.

Comment: I tried and still nothing, I might have missed something, I did it on android by using similar methods but on IOS references there is a mention about usage of FrameBuffer but it is an OpenGLES 2.0 reference. My both Android and IOS codes are on 1.0, it is done on Android and everything works on IOS but texture. :(

Comment: If you are willing to send me the project you may find my email on my profile page and I will take a look into it. From the data you have given here and the results you are getting it is hard to do anything but keep shooting in the dark and hope to hit the issue.

Comment: Hi, i sent a simplified code to your email, thank you Matic!

Comment: Why are you targeting OpenGL ES 1.x? If you're developing in Swift you can't support iOS older than 7.0, and iOS 7 requires devices that support OpenGL ES 2.

Comment: Hi rickster, I developed it first on Android and trying to pass to iOS, does not matter if it is 2.0 or 1.1 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the non POT (power of two) textures are not supported out of the box. I believe there are some extensions for that but I wouldn't bother with that.

Anyway the texture dimensions must be POT (2, 4, 8, 16...) so you have 2 options in doing so. You can create a POT context when getting the raw image data pointer and resize the image to a desired POT size scaling the image in the process. A more common way is to create a large enough texture with NULL data pointer and then use `glTexSubImage` with original image size parameters to send the data to the texture. This procedure also requires you to change the texture coordinates so instead of 1.0 you will have `imageWidth/textureWidth`, same for height. The second procedure need a bit more effort but is usually used to be upgraded into texture atlas procedure (putting multiple images onto the same texture).

Then again the fastest procedure is simply resizing your image in Photoshop or whatever to be 128x128 for instance. Just a note for POT dimensions should not need to be the same, 128x64 should be valid as well.

Comment: Thank you, I have just rendered my first iOS texture thanks to you, still long way to go for the app. :)